# Characterize algebras of the "topological simplices" operad

Tags: ct.category-theory, probability-distributions, operads

The operad of topological simplices, which I'll denote $\Delta$, has as $n$-ary operations the set
$$
\Delta_n:=\left\{P\colon\{1,\ldots,n\}\to[0,1]\;\middle|\;1=\sum_{i=1}^n P(i)\right\}
$$
of probability distributions on an $n$-element set; composition is by "weighted sum".

A $\Delta$-algebra consists of a pair $(X,h)$ where $X:\mathbf{Set}$ is a set and $h\colon\sum_{n:\mathbb{N}}\Delta_n\times X^n\to X$ is a function, satisfying the usual identity and composition laws.

Every [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) is an $\Delta$-algebra. One might be tempted to think that these are precisely the $\Delta$-algebras, except for the fact that every monoid (i.e. every algebra of the terminal plain operad) is also a $\Delta$-algebra. In terms of $\Delta$-algebras, monoids discard the probabilistic weighting of each element and instead just react to the list of elements; that is, $h$ factors through $\sum_{n:\mathbb{N}}X^n\to X$. On the other hand, convex sets discard the 0-weighted elements.

**Question:** How can we characterize the $\Delta$-algebras?

Comment: I don't understand the claim that $\Sigma_n$ acts freely on $\Delta_n$. No group acts freely on $\Delta_n$ by Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: @mme: the trivial group feels snubbed.  Yes I am a group!

Comment: Thanks @mme, I removed that part. I was confused because I've read multiple times, and I guess taken it on faith, that polynomial monads correspond to ∑-free operads. I'll have to dig deeper into this claim. Thanks again for pointing this out.

Comment: I was pointed to Leinster's [Entropy and Diversity book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02113.pdf), which has a family of such algebras as example 12.1.5.(iv).

Comment: I think $\Delta$ is cofibrant as a non-symmetric operad, so I believe one actually expects that the homotopy type of every infinite loop space occurs as a nonsymmetric algebra over it.

Comment: @DavidSpivak Regarding the $\Sigma$-freeness, I think in Leinster's book this operad is meant as a nonsymmetric operad. If you take the associated symmetric operad, via the operation $\Sigma_n \cdot O(n)$ then you do get a $\Sigma$-free symmetric operad. 12.1.5(i) is the terminal operad, and he definitely means non-symmetric because algebras over the terminal symmetric operad are commutative monoids. The associated $\Sigma$-operad of 12.1.5(i) is $Ass(n) = \Sigma_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @DavidWhite Right, in that book I'm using nonsymmetric operads only, as per Definition 12.1.1 and the comments between 12.1.2 and 12.1.3. The symmetric operad $\Delta$ is certainly interesting too, but it turns out that the symmetries aren't needed for what I was doing, namely, characterizing entropy operadically.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, @DavidWhite. I knew this somewhere in my mind, but I guess I hadn't used it enough to have it handy when confronted with the question.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to notice is that every element in $\Delta_n$, for $n \geq 2$, is obtained by iterated composition of elements of $\Delta_2$ (these are parametrized by elements $t$ in the unit interval). In other words, the binary operations for this theory generate all the operations, and in a specific way: for a model or algebra $X$, letting $\theta$ be any element of $\Delta_n$, and denoting the operation associated with $\theta$ by $m_\theta: X^n \to X$, there exist elements $t_1, \ldots, t_{n-1} \in \Delta_2$ such that (associating to the right)

$$m_\theta(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = m_{t_1}(x_1, m_{t_2}(x_2, \ldots m_{t_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}, x_n)\ldots )) \qquad (1)$$
(Pause for a moment to consider the example of convex sets. Here $m_t(x, y) = tx + (1-t)y$.) For $\theta = (\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n)$ in the interior of the simplex $\Delta_n$, the $t_i \in \Delta_2$ are uniquely determined by the formulas

$$t_1 = \theta_1, \qquad t_i = \frac{\theta_i}{1 - \theta_1 - \ldots - \theta_{i-1}}$$
for $1 < i < n$. But regarding points $\theta$ on the boundary of $\Delta_n$: as soon as $t_i = 1$, the remaining parameters $t_{i+1}, t_{i+2}, \ldots, t_{n-1}$ are no longer uniquely determined; indeed, for any choice of those parameters past $t_i = 1$, equation (1) holds. Put differently,

$$m_1(x, m_t(y, z)) = m_1(m_1(x, y), z) \qquad (2)$$
is an equation that holds universally in $\Delta$-algebras, and it follows that

$$m_1(x, m_s(y, z)) = m_1(x, m_t(y, z))$$
is an identity that holds for all $s, t \in \Delta_2$.

All of this holds in particular for operations $m_\theta$ that are derived from binary operations $m_t$ by iterated composition, sometimes associating to the left. In other words, we have equations

$$m_s(m_t(x, y), z) = m_{st}(x, m_{\frac{s-st}{1-st}}(y, z)) \qquad (3)$$
(provided that $st \neq 1$) which play the role of associativity equations. This may look strange at first, but for the example of convex algebras, it's a simple calculation based on rearranging convex combinations:

$$m_s(m_t(x, y), z) = s(tx + (1-t)y) + (1-s)z = stx + (1-st)\left(\frac{s-st}{1-st} y + \frac{1-s}{1-st} z\right).$$

> So, we may characterize $\Delta$-algebras as sets $X$ equipped with binary operations $m_t$, with $t$ ranging over $[0, 1]$, subject to the associativity conditions (2) and (3) above.

(We could even use equations (2) and (3) to set up a rewrite system for derived iterated compositions of binary operations, as tracked by planar binary trees, where in each application of of these cases we rewrite the left side of the equation to the right side.)

There are a number of subsidiary consequences of (3). For example, mirroring equations of type (2), we have the equation

$$m_0(m_t(x, y), z) = m_0(x, m_0(y, z)). \qquad (4)$$
So $m_0, m_1$ are associative each in their own right, and equations (2) and (4) state their "absorption" properties, and there are some other mild curiosities like

$$m_s(m_0(x, y), z) = m_0(x, m_s(y, z)), \qquad m_1(m_t(x, y), z) = m_t(x, m_1(y, z)).$$

Comment: With $\Delta$ as a non-symmetric operad, I believe that your $m_s$ subject to the associativity equation (3) is a generators-and-relations description of $\Delta$. This should essentially be the content of Prop 3.3 in [A presentation of the category of stochastic matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2554) (though I haven't thought it through carefully).

Comment: In the direction of something more elegant than (3), an intriguing aspect of convex combinations is that the algebraic theory of a binary convex combination operation $x \ast y := sx + (1-s)y$ with fixed coefficient $s$ contains equations given by idempotency $x \ast x = x$ and mediality $(w * x) * (y * z) = (w * y) * (x * z)$, and these present the algebraic theory if and only if $s$ is transcendental. This was proven by Fajtlowicz and Mycielski in [On convex linear forms](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02485731).

Comment: Combining idempotency and mediality also shows that $\ast$ distributes over itself. This observation leads to the [Alexander quandle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles#Examples_and_applications).

Comment: Thanks, Tobias; interesting observations. It's certainly not true that all $\Delta$-algebras will manifest idempotency, mediality, etc. of one of these $\ast$ operations, as the example of monoids being $\Delta$-algebras makes clear enough. (By the way, you mentioned my (3), but it's (2) and (3) together that give the relations.)

Comment: Yes, I agree -- I probably should have been more explicit about this, but that's why I said "algebraic theory of convex combinations" rather than "operad of convex combinations" :) This stuff may be relevant in case that the OP is secretly interested in the algebraic theory rather than just in the operad.

Comment: Well, any generator and relations description of an operad will give you a generators and relations description of an algebraic theory, but we still can't get the equations you wrote down if the OP accepts any monoid as a particular type of $\Delta$-algebra. I can make sense of your remark if the $\Delta_n$ are supposed to be (opposite to) finitely generated free algebras of a Lawvere theory; for example, $\Delta_1$ has just one element, so of course we would get idempotency, but of course that would radically change the question -- even if OP is secretly also interested in that question.

Comment: Yes, I'm not claiming that my comments are relevant to the original question as such. Based in part on past conversations with the OP, I've just been suspecting that what he's *actually* interested in (in addition to $\Delta$) may be algebraic properties of convex combinations.